# How to re-subscribe to socket.io events after reconnection in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a Socket service which implements a connection to socket.io and have some subscription methods, like "on" and "off".

I import this service to components so they can subscribe to socket io events. This is done in the componentDidMount like this:

```
import Socket from '/services/

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Socket.on("my-event", data => console.log(data))
  }

}
```

Everything works perfect. But the problem occurs by the time reconnections are happen.

Sometimes after a successful auto reconnect after a disconnect, events won't reach and won't happen.
I mean, socket hangs up and emit disconnect event, automatically then it tries to reconnect and successfully does. But the "my-event" event doesn't getting fired.

I believe that it happens because the "my-event" listener listens to OLD socket which is now closed and replaced by a new one, so probably the event listener also should be replaced and restarted.

I have tried to send pings to the server every 15s and let the server to ping them back to client to keep socket alive - it improved the connectivity but still, sometimes socket hangs up and that's it, users will not get notified about "my-event" anymore, unless they commit a full refresh to the whole app.

What leads to understand that its not an internet connectivity issue, but something like wrong subscriptions.

What is the best practice in here and how to keep the components socket io events up to date with the replaced ones?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `socket.removeListener('my-event')` to delete the previous event